# Как преобразовать список целых чисел в одно целое число без использования строковых функций?

Tags: python, алгоритм, int

У меня есть список целых чисел, которые я хотел бы распечатать как одно целое число, но я не могу использовать функцию, связанную со строками

```
x_lst =[ 1, 4, 5 ,23, 34,4, 4 ,2,1,34,342 ]
print ( "".join(list(map(str, x_lst))))
```

> desired output:

Желаемый результат:

```
 145233444213434234
```

Вышеуказанный скрипт преобразует каждое целое число в строку, а затем сливает их вместе, но я не могу использовать `str ()`. Есть ли другой способ преобразовать этот список в одно целое число без использования чего-либо, связанного со строками?

Comment: Используйте только русский язык, пожалуйста!

Comment: *но я не могу использовать str ()* - почему? домашнее задание?

Comment: Dear user, at [RuSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) you can ask only in Russian. You can ask your question in English at [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @splash58 трудности перевода. "*Can't*" и "*may not*" на русский переводятся одинаково, но означают разные формы невозможности действия. "*Can't*" - я **физически** не могу это сделать, "*may not*" - мне **не разрешено** это делать.

Comment: @Евгений так, вроде, can :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you need to convert it to a single string exactly or you need to print it like single string?

Вам нужно конвертировать его именно в одну строку или вам нужно вывести его, как одну строку?

> You can use `end` key to print it without `\n`:

Вы можете использовать ключ `end`, чтобы вывести его без `\n`:

```
for x in x_lst:
    print(x, end='')
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так:

```
print(*x_lst, sep='')
```

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться рекурсией и десятичным логарифмом:

```
import math

def f(lst, pow=0):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst.pop() * 10**pow
    x = lst.pop()
    new_pow = math.ceil(math.log10(x))
    return x * 10**pow + f(lst, pow + new_pow)
```

---

```
In [150]: f(x_lst.copy())
Out[150]: 145233444334342
```

PS асимптотическая сложность алгоритма - `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

> You can use an integer division to convert list of integers to a single integer:

Вы можете использовать целочисленное деление, чтобы преобразовать список чисел в одно число:

```py
x_lst = [1, 4, 5 ,23, 34, 4, 4, 2, 1, 34, 342]
result = 0

for x in x_lst:
    t = 0
    while x:
        t *= 10
        t += x%10
        x //= 10

    while t:
        result *=10
        result += t%10
        t //= 10

    del t

print(result)
```

> Result:

Результат:

```
1452334442134342
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно каждый раз брать число из конца списка, умножать его на 10 в степени разряда текущего результата и прибавлять к нему текущий результат.

```
x_lst =[1, 4, 5 ,23, 34, 4, 4 ,2, 1, 34, 342]
x_lst.reverse()

result = x_lst.pop(0)

for x in x_lst:
    n, i = result, 0
    while n > 0:
        n = n // 10
        i += 1
    result = x * (10 ** i) + result

print(result)
```